# CSS overflow property example that shows box is clipped to its padding edge

Tags: html, css

As per [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html),

> Whenever overflow occurs, the 'overflow' property specifies whether a box is clipped to its padding edge, and if so, whether a scrolling mechanism is provided to access any clipped out content.

I really cannot wrap around my head this line.

> **whether a box is clipped to its padding edge**

Can anyone give me good example for this statement.

Thanks
dkj

Comment: That actually seems incorrect to me considering the fact that margin and borders also play a part in the overflow of any element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is info about the box model in CSS (look for "padding edge"): https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html

The padding edge is the boundary formed by the content and its padding.

Clipping some on-screen object means cutting off a section of the object, usually whenever that section is out of bounds of its container. For example, if you are playing a game and half of a building is off-screen, that half is clipped and not visible outside of the game window.

So, a box being clipped to its padding edge means that any part of the box (for example, the text within a div) will be cut off if it goes beyond the padding edge.

The overflow property controls what happens when some content goes outside of its container. It can either cause a scroll-bar to appear, be hidden, or be shown outside of the container.

Answer (score 1):

It means that a box with overflow and padding is going to contain the content to within the padding margins, but display as larger. See below for working example.

```css
#pad {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#noPad {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="pad">
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
</div>
<div id="noPad">
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
  Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet Lorum Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the CSS box model. This is a visual representation of it:

[image]

If the size of the content surpasses the padding edge of the element, then **clipping** occurs and the `overflow:;` property allows you to give it a scrollbar or use the different options specified [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html).

Here, content overflows the size of the `div` (i.e. it goes beyond its padding edge) and an `overflow` property is specified (`scroll`):

```css
div {
  height:200px;
  overflow-Y:scroll;
  border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```